# On an asp.net Website, does each logged in user have their own instance "copy" of the source code being run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, software-design

I'm unsure how to word this question but I have a question regarding how asp.net and C# handle "instances" or "copies" of the source that runs and if there can be any sort of "cross pollination" between them when used by different users.

To summarise the question, can person A who is using the website at a particular time, get access to things that person B is doing if they are also on the website at the same time (this is what I want to avoid and confirm).

I understand how OOP works and this question is adding a layer on top of that to understand how isolated the code gets as will be described below.

For example, say there are 10 users who have signed up for a system with individual authentication (as created by VS).

And you have source code that you've written which performs various functions.

When person A uses the website and performs various operations, do they have their own "copy" of the source that's running for them?

If person B decides to use the website at the same time, do they also have their own "copy" of the source or are they using the same source that's also being used for person A?

As I understand it, every time you have a class and you instantiate it using a constructor, you have a new object of that item which is used and then destroyed later on when not needed.

Taking this thought one step above, does a user who's using the system have their own copy of the whole isolated source?

For example, there are static classes where there is only ever going to be 1 instance of it all the time. Does person A share the same static class as person B or do they each have their own static class?

Say for example, I have a class, which has global properties instead of method properties.

```
public partial class HelperMethods
{
    private static string Item1 = "StaticString1";

    private const string Item2 = "constString2";
    private const string Item3 = "constString3";

    public BlockingCollection<Task> Collection1 = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    public BlockingCollection<Task> Collection2 = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    public BlockingCollection<Task> Collection3 = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    public BlockingCollection<Task> Collection4 = new BlockingCollection<Task>();   

    public ApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public HelperMethods(int id) {
        using (var database = new DatabaseEntities()) {
            CurrentUser = //database call here with ID.
        }
    }
}
```

Does user A and user B have their own separate copy of all these items (for example Collection1) or are these items shared between each other?

If user A adds items to Collection1, and at the same time user B adds items to Collection1, would they be adding the items to the same collection or would they be completely separate from each other?

So to simplify and summarise briefly what I am trying to understand, when user A and user B both log onto the website, do they each get a copy of "HelperMethods" (let's say HelperMethods is the whole program for simplicity) and is isolated from each other or does C# do something else where there's actually ever only one copy of HelperMethods and every user that uses the system just get the constructor method and share everything else that's in global parameters?

An image example would be as follows:

Scenario 1:
Person A
(Has copy of class HelperMethods and all items in it.)
Person B
(Has copy of class HelperMethods and all items in it.)

Scenario 2:
(HelperMethods - exposes all global parameters)
Person A (has copy of the HelperMethod constructor only.)
Person B (has copy of the HelperMethod constructor only.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The static members of the HelperMethods class will be shared across all users. They will not be separate for each request/user.
A static member is owned by the ASP.NET worker process, it is common for all users. The instance variables of course will be separate for each user.

Comment: Ah I see, so asp.Net basically uses something similar to Scenario 2 on my question then I take it? The "source" is owned by the asp.Net worker process and each user just gets a copy of the instance methods / variables. So does this mean StaticString1 will be the same between user A and B, but constString 2 and Collection1 - 4 are all specific to the users? User A who is adding items to the global property Collection1 will not be affected by User B if they add to Collection1 (as they will have their own copy)?

Comment: Just want to ask regarding this link - https://forums.asp.net/t/1445372.aspx?When+to+use+static+methods - the accepted answer says "Though it is right that only one object of static class is created but it will get destroyed as soon as your page processing is done since Web application is stateless hence nothing is preserved and that object belongs to the current user and and not others. Thus each user will have its own instance created and destroyed". Does this mean that user A and B will never access the same static variables? Or will they both access it if they're using it at the same time?

Comment: From what I understand your static variable will remain available till the AppDomain is active. So if some your static variable is modified by User A, the modified value will be available to User B till the time the AppDomain is not reset. IIS has its own logic of resetting the AppDomain and it is configurable. Also, in case the code was recompiled for some reason say some change somewhere, then also you stand to lose the modified value. Other than that the static member should be available and accessible to all users.